# axiom of foundation of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I have found two different statements on axiom of foundation of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory in two different books as:

1) every nonempty set contains an element that is not an element of any
other element in the set.

2) Every non-empty set $x$ contains a member $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are disjoint sets.

These two are not equivalent statements. Am I correct ?

Comment: Which books did you find these formulations in? When written formally with only $\in$ it is easy to misread the axiom. It is also possible that whoever wrote the book made a mistake (which may or may not have been corrected since then).

Comment: I’ve a suspicion that a $\in$ got turned around in (1).

Answer (score 5):

They are not equivalent.  In fact, (1) is actually refutable under a weak subtheory of ZF.  Consider any inductive set $X$.  Then for each $u \in X$ we have that $u \in u \cup \{ u \} \in X$.  Thus $X$ has no element as described in (1).